# Non-linear Dynamical Systems and Quantitave Finance

Tags: reference-request, nonlinear, dynamic

The vast majority of what I have read about quantitave finance is to do with option pricing and time series analysis for forecasting. However the economy as a whole behaves as a dynamic system with people forecasting stock prices then having a direct impact on future stock prices.

I have read some interesting research on this in terms of a general economic viewpoint, but has there been anything in terms of a quantitive finance outlook? The economic theory is generally called Complex Economics but I couldn't find an a analagous Complex Quantitave Finance.

Answer (score 3):

This book might be what you are looking for:

[Theory of Financial Risk and Derivative Pricing. From Statistical Physics to Risk Management by J.-P. Bouchaud and M. Potters](http://books.google.de/books?id=AJsgAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=inauthor%3A%22Jean-Philippe%20Bouchaud%22&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)

As one reviewer from amazon wrote:

> Econophysics (the application of techniques developed in the
>   physical sciences to economic, business and financial problems) has
>   emerged as a newly active field of interdisciplinary research. `Theory
>   of Financial Risks' (written by two of the pioneers of this field)
>   highlights very clearly the contribution that physicists can make to
>   quantitative finance. From the outset the point of view of the book is
>   one of empirical observation (of the statistical properties of asset
>   price dynamics) followed by the development of theories attempting to
>   explain these results and enabling quantitative predictions to be
>   made. This philosophy is reflected in the structure of the book. [...]

Excerpts can be found on the accompanying site of Cambridge University Press: [Here](http://www.cambridge.org/de/academic/subjects/physics/econophysics-and-financial-physics/theory-financial-risk-and-derivative-pricing-statistical-physics-risk-management-2nd-edition)

*EDIT*
I know of no current overarching book but there are several papers out there that address the issues of evolving trading strategies in an artificial stock market. Try the following [google search](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=artificial%20stock%20market%20evolution%20trading%20strategies).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had a look through the book but am not sure it is quite what I am looking for. To be more clear, a very basic example would be to start with a number of trading strategies and a dummy stock market and let them play out in a simulation. The strategies that performed best would survive and breed in an evolutionary way. 

I have read about this example in an economics book but was wondering whether this has been expanded on in a quantitative finance setting.

Comment: @rwolst: Ok, then you should modify your question accordingly because it wasn't clear what exactly you were looking for. I will see what I can do for you to give you more references.

Comment: @rwolst: See my edit.